# Spring-Data-Neo4j: Cannot create relationship between entities using neo4jtempalte createRelationshipBetween)() method

Tags: java, spring-data-neo4j

I am create relationship between two nodes using spring-data-neo4j, but the relation ship not persist. There is no exception thrown by server. when i fetch the node, there is a null values in it. I am using Neo4jTemplate `createRelationshipBetween()` method. Follwoing is my code:

Relationship Entity:

```
@RelationshipEntity(type=RelationshipTypes.FRIEND)
public class FriendsRelationship extends BaseEntity{

@StartNode
@Getter @Setter
private Person person;
@EndNode
@Getter @Setter
private Person friend;
@Getter @Setter
private String friendsType;
}


public class CreateEntitiesRelationship {

@Autowired
private Neo4jTemplate neo4jTemplate;

-------------------------------

public FriendsRelationship createRelationshipBetweenPersons(Person person, Person friend, 
        Class<FriendsRelationship> relationshipEntity, String friendshipType) {
    FriendsRelationship relationship = neo4jTemplate.createRelationshipBetween(person, friend, relationshipEntity, RelationshipTypes.FRIEND, false);
    neo4jTemplate.save(relationship);
    return relationship;
}
}
```

Whht actual problem is , i am unable to figure out. I am new if Neo4j.

Comment: Try annotating the *createRelationshipBetweenPersons* method with *@Transactional*.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
 {
    Person _person = neo4jTemplate.save(person); 
    Person _friend = neo4jTemplate.save(friend);
    FriendsRelationship relationship = neo4jTemplate.createRelationshipBetween(_person, _friend, relationshipEntity, RelationshipTypes.FRIEND, false);
    neo4jTemplate.save(relationship);//optional. saved by default
    return relationship;
}
```